# kendo main widget HTML needs to be removed manually

Tags: kendo-ui

Once a kendo widget is destroyed, it and its HTML is no longer needed in the page. The framwork cleans all HTML outside the widget but not inside widget. So I need to write few lines of code to remove the HTML in main widget every time I destroy a widget.
How can I avoid this boilerplate code to remove HTML in the main widget's element? Why does not kendo clean HTML inside main Widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kendo widget's `destroy()` method is just preparing widget to remove from the site. Assume that you want do remove a big container contains one or few widgets. Removing all widget's html separately using `destroy()` method and then remove container will cause decline in performance.

I don't know where you see few lines of code to destroy and remove widget - it's just two:

```
$("#widget").data("yourWidget").destory();
$("#widget").remove();
```

And, you can easly create your own global function to destroy and remove widget:

```
function deleteWidget(kendoWidget){
    var element = kendoWidget.element;
    kendoWidget.destroy();
    element.remove();
}
```

If you want to recreate widget you can use:

```
function emptyWidget(kendoWidget){
    var element = kendoWidget.element;
    kendoWidget.destroy();
    element.empty();
}
```

And then you can then use your empty html elemnt to create new widget.

More about destroy widgets in official kendo documentation: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/widgets/destroy.